# Does the minimum connection time of ocean surface currents depend on the patch scale?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, statistical-mechanics, renormalization, scales, oceanography

The Nature paper "[The timescales of global surface-ocean connectivity](https://www.nature.com/articles/ncomms11239)" attempts to model "minimum connectivity times (Min-T), or distances based on the fastest times that particles can travel from one location to another." The authors divided the ocean's surface into 11,116 patches that were approximately 2° × 2° in size, and estimated the minimum amount of time that it would take for any water from one patch to flow any other patch. Their headline conclusion was that the average minimal transit time between two random patches was less than 10 years.

But, even if we accept their modeling assumptions, is this 10 years a meaningful quantity by itself? Doesn't it depend on the patch size, with the transit time increasing without bound as the patches get smaller? (That's my intuition, based on imagining individual fluid parcels at the ocean surface following a biased random walk subject to the constraint that the density stays uniform.) I would imagine the transit time matrices would display some kind of fractal-like structure where the relevant time scale depends on the resolution length scale, and the relevant characterization is not a single timescale but instead some kind of functional dependence of connection time on spatial resolution (i.e. patch size), perhaps characterized by some kind of critical exponent or something.

The alternative is that the minumum transit time saturates to a finite limit as we go to small patch size, in which case there really is a single relevant "universal" (i.e. asymptotically scale-independent) time scale. But this seems counterintuitive to me; I would imagine that the connection time diverges to infinity in the limit of small patches (loosely analogous to a "UV divergence" in field theory).

The paper only mentions the patch size in the methods section, while it presents the minimum transit time (less than 10 years) in the abstact, perhaps suggesting that the authors seem to think that the latter quantity is somewhat "universal" and independent of the patch size.